Dudas con password_verify en PHP
Estoy probando password_verify en PHP, pero no consigo hacerla funcionar.
Los datos que recibo de la base de datos es un array con los siguientes valores.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [usuario] => usuario1 [clave] => 0000 ) )
Tanto el campo usuario, como el campo clave son del tipo varchar

<?php
require_once("miconexion.php");

// Retrieve user input
$username = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['clave'];

try {
    // Prepare the SQL statement with placeholders
    $sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :username LIMIT 1");

    // Bind parameters to avoid SQL injection
    $sql->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
    // Execute the query
    $sql->execute();

    // Fetch the result as an associative array
    $resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Check if user exists and verify password
    if ($resultado && password_verify($password, $resultado[0]['clave'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: portada.html');
        exit();  // Ensure the script stops after redirection
    } else {
        echo "Nombre de usuario o password incorrecto";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error en la consulta: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>


Para que funcione, debiste usar password_hash al momento de hacer el INSERT. Es extraño ese 0000 como clave, parece que la contraseña no está hasheada. También, el campo destinado a guardar el hash, debe tener un tamaño adecuado, para que no quede truncado. Revisa aquí o bien aquí para más detalles.

Te pongo un ejemplo básico de funcionamiento de la función que estas usando:
<?php

$pw = '123456';
$hash = password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

echo $pw . ' => ' . $hash . PHP_EOL; // 123456 => $2y$10$o0Uk8V6gzXNSW/EZBWvd1OoC7O6UzrU3LRbDMIqxYDou2KJGRXdUa
var_dump(password_verify($pw, $hash)); // true

Donde password_verify acepta dos argumentos: el string original, que debe coincidir exactamente con el string que se uso para generar el hash, tanto los caracteres, mayúsculas, minúsculas y los ESPACIOS en blanco.
Si password_verify devuelve falserevisa los strings que le estas pasando.
Revisa si $resultado tiene contenido antes de tratar de usar password_verify.
Doc:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Quiero aportar a esta publicación, agregando un control de errores durante el desarrollo.
Durante el desarrollo en PHP, se pueden agregar opciones, y depuraciones simples, para que el código nos muestre de mejor manera los errores que obtenemos al desarrollar.
Para ello podemos usar echo o incluso var_dump.
Destaco, esto es útil SOLO PARA EL DESARROLLO, luego podemos quitarlos.
Además, si usamos un archivo para el log, podemos enviar esta información ahí.
En el código del usuario, podemos agregar varias mejoras para esto:
Mostrar errores más detallados:
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Mostrar valores, antes de realizar comparaciones: (en especial si estos fallan)
echo "Usuario ingresado: $username <br>";
echo "Contraseña ingresada: $password <br>";
//después...
echo $resultado

Verificar que la consulta haya sido exitosa
if ($sql->execute()) {
    echo "Consulta ejecutada correctamente. <br>";
} else {
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta. <br>";
}

Obtener el resultado como arreglo asociativo, y mostrar el resultado.
$resultado = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($resultado) {
    echo "Resultado encontrado: " . print_r($resultado, true) . "<br>";
} else {
    echo "No se encontró ningún usuario con ese nombre.<br>";
}

Y acá el resultado completo para el usuario
<?php
// Mostrar todos los errores y advertencias de PHP (solo en desarrollo)
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("miconexion.php");

$username = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['clave'];

// Mostrar valores para depuración (solo en desarrollo)
echo "Usuario ingresado: $username <br>";
echo "Contraseña ingresada: $password <br>";

try {
    $sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :username LIMIT 1");

    // Vincular parámetros para evitar inyecciones SQL
    $sql->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
    // Ejecutar la consulta y mostrar resultados
    if ($sql->execute()) {
        echo "Consulta ejecutada correctamente. <br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta. <br>";
    }

    // Obtener el resultado como un arreglo asociativo
    $resultado = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    // Mostrar resultado para depuración (solo en desarrollo)
    if ($resultado) {
        echo "Resultado encontrado: " . print_r($resultado, true) . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "No se encontró ningún usuario con ese nombre.<br>";
    }

    if ($resultado && password_verify($password, $resultado['clave'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: portada.html');
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Nombre de usuario o password incorrecto.<br>";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error en la consulta: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
}
?>

